# Extending Apache Kafka to web and mobile apps

Tags: push-notification, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am exploring Apache Kafka for building an application and it really suits our needs. However, as part of our application, we also need to push data streams and notifications to user’s apps and web dashboards. AFAIK Kafka clients do not support JavaScript so integration with web dashboards seems to be a challenge.

I want to know

What would be the best way to extend messages received in Kafka topic to web dashboards, assuming thousands of logged-in users. ( web socket is no option here)

What are the best available Kafka clients for iOS and Android.

Also, I am wondering that generally speaking, what would be the best way to fan-out messages coming in from a Kafka topic to thousands of end devices ( like websites, phones, IoT terminals, etc.). Any general or tool-specific suggestion would be awesome.

-Shyam

Comment: `AFAIK Kafka clients do not support JavaScript `, https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node, https://kafka.js.org/, https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka

Comment: you can also try running a kafka rest frontend - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Answer (score 0):

`kafka-connect` is a good use-case.
Please check the details here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-connect.

The other option is to have a micro-service to `produce` and `consume`. It is a good option if you later want to do additional operations before publish or after publishing.